# Getting warning that cant change state on an unmounted component even when my component is mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to allow the user to proceed to the route only if he is a registered user. I do that with axios post request and in the .then method changing the state.route to the route to proceed to but if he is not it will link him to the same page as he is.

This is my code

```
import axios from "axios";

const LOGIN_URL = "http://localhost:5555/api/logIn";

export class LoginComponent extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.usernameRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      forgotPassword: false,
      username: "",
      password: "",
      email: "",
      route: "/login",
      response: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.usernameRef.current.focus();
  }
  Login = () => {
    axios
      .post(LOGIN_URL, { username: this.state.username, password: this.state.password })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.HandleUsername(this.state.username);
        this.setState({
          route: "/items",
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data);
        this.setState({
          response: err.response.data,
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="PageLogin">
        {this.state.response}
        <div id="Login" className="container">
          <form id="login-div" className="row justify-content-center align-items-end">
            <input
              ref={this.usernameRef}
              className="col-6 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"
              id="login-input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.username}
              placeholder="Username"
              onChange={this.HandleUsername}
            />
          </form>
          <form id="login-div" className="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <input
              className="col-6 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4"
              id="login-input"
              type="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              placeholder="Password"
              onChange={this.HandlePassword}
            />
          </form>
          <div id="login-div" className="row">
            <Link to={this.state.route} className=" mx-auto col-6 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-5 align-self-start">
              <button
                id="login-button"
                type="button"
                onClick={this.Login}
                className="  mx-auto  col-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-xl-11"
              >
                Login
              </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I know i could have use name and event.target.name to have one handler for all but its not the issue now

Comment: Hi, can you please remove the unwanted code from here that has no relation with your question for now so that it would be better to focus on your just issue generated code.

Comment: Yes just did it

Comment: I'd be willing to bet the click event is propagating to the link component and some navigation is occurring (even is it is just the same route) and `LoginComponent` is remounting (or close to it). You may be able to `preventDefault`|`stopPropagation` on it in the handler, but IMO you shouldn't mix the link and button like that. It is better to check authentication/registration/etc... in a route component (think Gatekeeper).

Comment: What is actually weird that the warning does not  occur when the response is an error

Comment: I think that I i will go with a away which the function return true or false and then use the ? operator to decide to which component it should link to

Comment: Really thank for the time and thoughts you invested in it appreciate it

Comment: So I dont know why but i just cant change the state no matter what , not matter what i do the warning is still there

Comment: When an error occurs and axios returns a rejected Promise you don't update `this.state.route`.